# How to sort all the files with a particular extension inside a directory in Cent OS 7 according to modification time?

Tags: linux, shell, centos

What command should I use to sort all the files in a project directory according to the date of modification?

Tried `ls -t` but it does not find the file and used `find` to find all the files of the specified type, but could not sort them.

Comment: Doesn't the `ls -t` do this?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar But that does not find the files in the subdirectories with that type. `find` was better solution.

Comment: @jww I had to answer my own question. So I guess that's the most I could do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this to find all the files of the type you are looking for and sorted by the last modified date.

```
find $directory -type f -name "*.type" -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%y %n" | sort
```

The above looks for all the files of type "type" and then sorts it according to the last modified timestamp.